# Check row existence in SQL Server with PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Actually I am dealing for my first time with **PowerShell** scripting.

By looking for a good solution in order to perform a `SELECT` on **SQL Server**, I found the code as follows:

```
Function IdentityProviderExistsDatabase {
    param(
        [string] $IdPIdentifier
    )

    $SQLQuery = $("SELECT [*] FROM [dbo].[IdPs] WHERE [IdPIdentifier] = '$IdPIdentifier'")

    $SQLConnect = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection  
    $SQLConnect.connectionstring = $SQLConnectionString

    $SQLConnect.Open()  

    $command = New-object system.data.sqlclient.SqlCommand   
    $command.connection = $SQLConnect  
    $command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
    while ($Reader.Read()) {
        $Reader.GetValue($1)
    }
}
```

The solution above works fine, but really I don't need to read any value; for my purposes, I'd just know if the query returns something, thus just if the record exists or not according to the `WHERE` clause.

Is there a way to perform this operation in a more elegant way than by checking the returned values inside the loop?

Comment: Simplest SQL would be: `$SQLQuery = $("SELECT top 1 1 RowExists FROM [dbo].[IdPs] WHERE [IdPIdentifier] = '$IdPIdentifier'")`

Comment: I second the `top 1 1` approach over count, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ExecuteScalar()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx). As per documentation,

> Use the ExecuteScalar method to retrieve a single value (for example,
>   an aggregate value) from a database.

Sample usage:

```
$SQLQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM..."
$SQLConnect = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(...)
$SQLConnect.Open()  
$command = New-object system.data.sqlclient.SqlCommand   
$command.connection = $SQLConnect  
$command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$scalar = $command.ExecuteScalar() # The select's result is stored in $scalar
$command.Dispose()
$SQLConnect.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just as for a count

```
 $SQLQuery = $("SELECT count(*) result_count FROM [dbo].[IdPs] WHERE [IdPIdentifier] = '$IdPIdentifier'")
```

which would return one row

Comment: First of all, thanks. My question is not about the query, but about how to properly use the reader in order to have a `$true` or `$false` if the record exists or not, but without put a condition inside the loop (if possible, of course).